# Como mostrar solo los campos con determinado valor en Sonata Admin ShowFields

Tags: php7, symfony4

Tengo una entidad intereses, que tiene una relacion n - 1 con los usuarios. Es una Colección y puede estar a true o false. En el apartado del admin del Usuario (UserAdmin) cuando estoy en mostrar (ShowFields) necesito mostrar solo los intereses activos del usuario (los que ha seleccionado como que sí le interesan). Pero no consigo que Sonata me devuelva el valor filtrado, siempre me muestra todos los intereses existentes (como un link a otra ventana donde veo la entidad interestsAdmin y sí me especifica si está a true o false) ¿Hay alguna manera de aplicar una query en la parte de showFields? solo lo he encontrado en la documentación para el list y no me lo está aplicando.

```
 ->add('interests',  CollectionType::class, array(
            'class' => 'App::Interest',
            'query_builder' => function(EntityManagerInterface $er) {
                return $er->createQueryBuilder('i')
                    ->andWhere('i.value = :value')
                    ->andWhere('i.user = :user')
                    ->orderBy('i.newsletter', 'ASC')
                    ->setParameters([
                        'value' => 1,
                        'user' => $this->user
                    ]);
            }
        ))
```

Answer (score 0):

La única manera que he encontrado es poniendo un template personalizado de twig donde recorro el objeto y solo muestro lo que quiero, pero no he conseguido filtrar desde el php. Además esto me parece un atraso puesto que podría cambiar el modelo y el twig quedaría obsoleto...